# VB Script to Delete files in subfolder

Tags: vbscript

I am in need of VB Script to delete unnecessary / unwanted files (with different extension, but last name of files are common such as ABC123DEF.pdf, ABC456DEF.pdf, QWE145_source.xml, QWE784_source.xml etc)  from sub-folders

Can anybody help on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are not going to do your job. What have your tried? What is the trouble? Where? Show us your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a skeleton script that traverses a folder tree:

```
Step00.vbs:

Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

WScript.Quit Main()

Function Main()
  Dim sDir : sDir = "..\test"
  Dim oWorker : Set oWorker = New cWorker
  Main = traverseDir(goFS.GetFolder(sDir), oWorker)
End Function

Class cWorker
  Public Sub processFile(oFile)
    WScript.Echo oFile.Path
  End Sub
End Class

Function traverseDir(oDir, oWorker)
  traverseDir = 0
  Dim oF
  For Each oF In oDir.Files
      oWorker.processFile oF
  Next
  For Each oF In oDir.SubFolders
      traverseDir = traverseDir(oF, oWorker)
  Next
End Function
```

Output:

```
cscript step00.vbs
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\13415663\test\13415663.notes
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\13415663\test\13415663.kpf
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\13415663\test\13415663-UE15.prj
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\13415663\test\vbs\step00.vbs
```

The Main function passes a folder and a worker to the traverseDir function
and returns an exit code to be passed to the caller (OS). The traverseDir
function sends each file in a directory to the worker's processFile sub, call
itself recursively for each subfolder, and returns an error code to the
caller (Main/previous instance of itself). The (trivial) worker just echos
the file's path.

Step01.vbs uses a worker with a hardcoded condition to determine which
files to delete:

```
Class cWorker
  Public Sub processFile(oFile)
    If "notes" = goFS.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name) Then
       WScript.Echo "will delete", oFile.Path
       oFile.Delete
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

output:

```
cscript step01.vbs
will delete E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\13415663\test\13415663.notes
```

Based on this proof of concept script you can enhance the traverseDir function
(error handling for not accessible folders, ...) and/or the cWorker class (more
complex condition, error handling, logging, ...).

**Update:**

See [this recursive folder access script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429422/603855) to get ideas for further enhancements of the skeleton.