# VB Script to move subfolder based on folder structure

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VB Script and I am in need of VB Script to move specific sub-folder based on folder name structure (i.e. pick-up of exact "abc" sub-folder from "test2" and need to move to "test1") and folder exact structure is as follows

- E:\test1\42\5423284\4967957\html
- E:\test1\43\5403284\4567051\html
- E:\test1\48\7723589\9977457\html
- E:\test1\47\5428284\2797932\html
- E:\test1\42\5468284\1487651\html

In above, "html" folder does not contain any "abc" sub-folder

I want to move below "abc" sub-folder to above "html" folder

- E:\test2\42\5423284\4967957\html\abc
- E:\test2\43\5403284\4567051\html\abc
- E:\test2\48\7723589\9977457\html\abc
- E:\test2\47\5428284\2797932\html\abc
- E:\test2\42\5468284\1487651\html\abc

Can any body help on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer to your "delete folder" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429422/603855):

Just provide a method like:

```
  Public Function processFolder(oFolder)
    WScript.Echo "looking at", oFolder.Path
    processFolder = True
    If "abc" = oFolder.Name Then
       WScript.Echo "will move", oFolder.Path
       WScript.Echo "       to", Replace(oFolder.Path, "\df\", "\mf\")
       oFolder.Move Replace(oFolder.Path, "\df\", "\mf\")
       processFolder = False
    End If
  End Function
```