# Getting full path of a file

Tags: file, search, vbscript, find

I need to return the full path of a file by searching it using VB script. For example here's my folder:

[image]

And I want to search for a file named "sample1.txt" in C:\ directory and echo it.

The output would be, "**C:\test\test1\sample1.txt**"

Comment: Return to what? What do you intend to do with the path?

Comment: To put it in a variable. Or just echo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from here: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/vbscript-to-find-file-and-return-filtered-folder-path/28076.html

And tweaked it a bit:

```
Const fileName = "cFiles.vbs" 'Filename to search
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dir = "C:\Users\makoy\Documents\CommonFiles" 'Place directory to search

If fso.FolderExists(dir) Then _
file = FindFile(LCase(fileName), fso.GetFolder(dir))
If Len(file) = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: File Not Found"
    WScript.Quit 2
End If
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(file & "\..")
WScript.Echo folder & "\" & fileName


WScript.Quit
Function FindFile(ByRef sName, ByRef oFolder) 'As String
    FindFile = ""
    For Each file In oFolder.Files
        If LCase(file.Name) = sName Then
            FindFile = file
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next 'file
    For Each dir In oFolder.SubFolders
        FindFile = FindFile(sName, dir)
        If Len(FindFile) Then _
        Exit Function
    Next 'dir
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

- Write a [recursive directory walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415663/vb-script-to-delete-files-in-subfolder/13416248#13416248) and use the .Path
- Use .Run or .Exec to `dir /s /b` and capture/process the output